# NUnit 3.4.1 how to open the tool and test?

Tags: nunit

I have installed Nunit 3.4 version using Nuget pacakage manager in visual studio 2013. there is only nunit.framework.DLL is available, so not sure how to open the tool and test the tester project that i have written. please help

Answer (score 0):

Install the [NUnit 3 Test Adapter for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d) and you can run the tests from the Visual Studio Test Explorer. You can also install the NUnit 3 Console app from http://nunit.org and run your tests from the command line.

Comment: Thanks, I can't install Nunit 3 console app from nuget package manager. please let me know how I can install it in project.

Comment: If you want to install the NUnit Console via NuGet, you need to install this package, https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Runners/. The runner will then be in a directory in your solution, `.\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.4.1\tools\` or similar...

Comment: Thanks again, what is the procedure if I want to install nunit console not using nuget. please

Comment: You can install the MSI from nunit.org and if will be in your program files

Comment: Hi - I am unable to ask a question in this forum. I receive error as You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to NUnit -> Tools -> Settings -> IDE Support -> Visual Studio -> Enable Visual Studio Support. Now you can use File -> Open Project to add sln files into NUnit